# Loop through columns creating summarise

Tags: r, for-loop, summarize

I want to loop through the columns of the df and extract a summary of the man, min, and max using the summarise() function.

So far, I've created the following, where all the columns of which I'd like a summary are captured in a list() assigned to vars.

```
vars <- list("npl_lnratio", "l_npl_lnratio", "llp_loans", "llp_npl", "eta", "cap",
             "roaa", "roae", "lta", "ltd", "efficiency", "cta", "g", "unemp", "inf", "hpi", "debt")

  
for (i in vars) {
  
  df5 %>%
    group_by(i) %>%
    count() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    summarize(mean(n), min(n), max(n))
    
}
```

Running this piece leads to the following error:

```
Error: Must group by variables found in `.data`.
* Column `i` is not found.
```

How can I create a for loop which does provide summaries of all the columns in the vars list?

Answer (score 1):

group_by only takes unquoted variables. One way to go around that would be the following.

```r
vars <- c("npl_lnratio", "l_npl_lnratio", "llp_loans", "llp_npl", "eta", "cap",
             "roaa", "roae", "lta", "ltd", "efficiency", "cta", "g", "unemp", "inf", "hpi", "debt")

  
for (i in vars) {
  
  df5 %>%
    group_by(across(all_of(i))) %>%
    count() %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    summarize(mean(n), min(n), max(n))
    
}
```